# Cannot import nltk under OSX

Tags: python-2.7, pip, nltk

I use pip `install -U nltk` to install it.
After pip list I can get nltk (3.0.0).
Also sys.path includes location of nltk.

But when run `import nltk`, it shows `ImportError: No module named nltk`

I use OSX Yosemite, python2.7

I cannot figure out why it happen.
Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the free Anaconda distribution of Python instead. NLTK comes pre-installed in Anaconda, along with many other popular packages for data analysis, etc. It's a lot easier than having to install & manage hundreds of separate packages individually.

https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/