# recurring issue with importing nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I have tried the following:

Install Setuptools: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Install Pip: easy_install pip

Install Numpy (optional): pip install -U numpy

Install NLTK: pip install -U nltk

When I test the installation by running python and then 'import nltk', I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named nltk
```

When I check to see if I have nltk installed by running

```
pip search nltk
```

I get the following, suggesting I do have it installed:

```
nltk                      - Natural Language Toolkit
  INSTALLED: 3.0.0 (latest)
metanl                    - Multilingual natural language tools, wrapping NLTK
                        and other systems.
wordgrapher               - Word Graph utility built with NLTK and TextBlob
bluestocking              - An information extraction toolkit built on top of
                            NLTK.
SloPOS                    - Part of speech tagger for Slovenian (SI) language
                            based on NLTK
estnltk                   - Open source tools for Estonian natural language
                            processing
```

What's is the issue and how can I resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What operating system are you using? What is the output of `pip -V`?

Comment: also helps to tell us what version of Python.

Comment: Anyway there are [tons of duplicate answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nltk+PYTHONPATH), please browse them, this question gets asked here about once a month. Add the keywords relevant to your platform, e.g. Ubuntu, Windows, MacOS.

Comment: pip 1.5.6 from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

Comment: What is the output of `which python`?

Comment: Which python giveS: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Comment: what does `which -a python` output?

Comment: what does `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"` output?

Comment: which -a python produces: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of python being run when you enter `python` in Terminal is the version from python.org, whereas `pip` is using Homebrew's version of Python. You'll need to edit your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` to change the order of your path so that Homebrew's Python is run instead.

To do this, open Terminal and enter

```
ls -al
```

and check the output to see if `.bashrc` and/or `.profile` exist. Next, use `cat` to check the contents of each file, looking for the presence of lines that start with `export PATH=...`. If only one file exists, or if both exist and only one defines `PATH`, then open that file in your favorite editor. On the last line, enter the following:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Save the file, completely close Terminal, and reopen it. If everything worked as expected, `which python` should now return `/usr/local/bin/python`. You can now run `python`, and once in the interpreter, running the command

```py
>>> import nltk
```

should import the module with no errors.

---

#### EDIT

Setting up the python.org version of Python to be your default is easier, as it's already in your `PATH`. The version of `pip` you're using is both outdated and installed for use with Homebrew, so we'll need to install a new version. First, though, we'll change the permissions of your installation so you don't need to use `sudo` every time you run `pip`. To do this, run

```
sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
```

This allows `pip` to install modules in `site-packages`, and scripts in the `bin` directory.

Next, we'll copy the contents of your Homebrew `site-packages` directory to the python.org `site-packages` directory, so you can use the modules you've already installed with `pip`. To do this, run

```
cp -R /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/pyth‌​on2.7/site-packages/* /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/pyth‌​on2.7/site-packages
```

Finally, download [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), change to the directory you downloaded it in, and run `python get-pip.py` (this is assuming you **haven't** changed your `PATH` as instructed above). This will set up the current version of `pip` (as of this writing it's 6.0.3) for use with python.org Python. You can now run `pip install modulename` to install packages.

Comment: thanks! Is there any possibility of using my current python version and importing nltk to that instead of changing my python path?

Comment: @chris could you clarify? Which version of Python (python.org or Homebrew) do you want to be using for your work?

Comment: I want to be able to use python.org python if possible!

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself a lot of hassle by using the Anaconda distribution of Python, as I recommended in a previous answer to a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27572421/4067134

> You might want to try the free Anaconda distribution of Python instead. NLTK comes pre-installed in Anaconda, along with many other popular packages for data analysis, etc. It's a lot easier than having to install & manage hundreds of separate packages individually.
>
> https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/